# Delete one item based on its position in a div (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

So what I want to do is delete the (example) third triangle (with index 4) when I hover in the `div` with the text "four".

My `jQuery` code (the first part just makes the octagon) the second part I wanted to get both of the indexes but than don't know where to go from there.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var triangles = $('.triangle');
  let amountOfTriangles = triangles.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < amountOfTriangles; i++) {
    let singleTriangle = triangles[i];
    var rotdeg = 45 * i;
    $(singleTriangle).css({
      "transform": "rotate(" + rotdeg + "deg)"
    });
  }

  var $elems = $('.item');
  var $tri = $('.triangle');
  $elems.hover(function(e) {
    var indexOfElem = $elems.index(this);
    var indexOfTri = $tri.index(this);
    console.log("You hover an element with an index of: " + indexOfElem);
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  height: 70%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.triangle {
  border-top: 120px solid #0003;
  border-left: 50px solid #0000;
  border-right: 50px solid #0000;
  border-bottom: 120px solid #0000;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.list {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.item {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #0003;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Zero</div>
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three</div>
  <div class="item">Four</div>
  <div class="item">Five</div>
  <div class="item">Six</div>
  <div class="item">Seven</div>
</div>
```

This is the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/26trjub5/) link that for some reason does not display the `console.log`

***EDIT***: The question i asked wasn't well enough explained so i am making this edit. I want to delete the triangle only for the duration of the hover.

Comment: See [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript) if you're just wanting to remove it from the array. Are you also wanting to remove it from the DOM?

Comment: Do you need  triangle to be removed ??

Comment: @Akhil Aravind yes i do. I want it to become transparent with a .css() command but the problem is i don't know how to associate the item div with the correct triangle

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/remove/  (you can dynamically construct a css selector using `nth-child(...)`)

Comment: @Christian i want to give it a css property to make it transparent so it keeps its position to later on remove the css propery and make it visible again.

Comment: @ne1410s i know but the problem is i cant associate the correct item div with its corresponding  (by index) triangle div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated answer

OP has clarified that he only wants the triangle to be hidden away when items are hovered on, so the solution is a lot more trivial than the previous iteration. What you need is simply to use `.eq(indexOfElem)` to toggle a class:

```
$elems.hover(function(e) {
    var indexOfElem = $elems.index(this);
    $triangles.eq(indexOfElem).addClass('hidden');
}, function(e) {
    var indexOfElem = $elems.index(this);
    $triangles.eq(indexOfElem).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

And in your CSS, the `.hidden` class can simply be:

```
.hidden { display: none }
```

See example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $triangles = $('.triangle');
  $triangles.each(function(i) {
    $(this).css({
      transform: 'rotate(' + (45 * i) + 'deg)'
    });
  });

  var $elems = $('.item');
  $elems.hover(function(e) {
    var indexOfElem = $elems.index(this);
    $triangles.eq(indexOfElem).addClass('hidden');
  }, function(e) {
    var indexOfElem = $elems.index(this);
    $triangles.eq(indexOfElem).removeClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 350px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.triangle {
  border-top: 120px solid #0003;
  border-left: 50px solid #0000;
  border-right: 50px solid #0000;
  border-bottom: 120px solid #0000;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.list {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #0003;
  width: 50px;
}

.triangle.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three</div>
  <div class="item">Four</div>
  <div class="item">Five</div>
  <div class="item">Six</div>
  <div class="item">Seven</div>
  <div class="item">Eight</div>
</div>
```

### Previous answer

What I would suggest is that instead of removing it based on the index of the element in the collection, you use `.data()` to store the index of each triangle instead. This is so that when a triangle is removed (which causes the `.index()` to change, since the length of the collection changes), the actual one-to-one matching between the items and the triangles still stays the same.

When you are applying the CSS transformation to your triangles, you can use `.data('index', i)` to store the index of the triangle. Even better: you can use jQuery's `.each()` to loop through your collection of triangles instead of relying on a for loop:

```
var $triangles = $('.triangle');
$triangles.each(function(i) {
    $(this).css({
        transform: 'rotate(' + (45 * i) + 'deg)'
    }).data('index', i);
});
```

Then, in the hover function, you can simply filter through the triangles collection and remove the corresponding one:

```
$elems.hover(function(e) {
    var indexOfElem = $elems.index(this);
    triangles.filter(function() {
        return $(this).data('index') === indexOfElem;
    }).remove();
});
```

Also, the reason why your `.hover()` function does not work in your fiddle is because your items are being overlaid by the triangles: assigning it `position: relative;` will fix the problem.

See proof-of-concept here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $triangles = $('.triangle');
  $triangles.each(function(i) {
    $(this).css({
      transform: 'rotate(' + (45 * i) + 'deg)'
    }).data('index', i);
  });

  var $elems = $('.item');
  $elems.hover(function(e) {
    var indexOfElem = $elems.index(this);
    $triangles.filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('index') === indexOfElem;
    }).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 350px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.triangle {
  border-top: 120px solid #0003;
  border-left: 50px solid #0000;
  border-right: 50px solid #0000;
  border-bottom: 120px solid #0000;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
}

.list {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #0003;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three</div>
  <div class="item">Four</div>
  <div class="item">Five</div>
  <div class="item">Six</div>
  <div class="item">Seven</div>
  <div class="item">Eight</div>
</div>
```

Comment: (this next part is fully my fault because i didn't explain my problem well enough). I was hoping the triangles would only disappear for the duration of the hover not until page refresh.

Comment: @Epik Pro-tip: it's always helpful to clarify upfront in the question itself.

Comment: yes this was completely my bad and i think i can get it working the way i want to by using mouse enter and mouse leave functions with your code (if it works i am going to mark it as the correct answer hoping people will look in the comments) EDIT: it does work =D

Comment: @Epik Updated answer for the scenario where you don't want to remove the elements but simply to hide them.